# Django - How to create users with the same username and password?

Tags: django, authentication, django-admin

I would like to ask if there is any way to create a user where the username and password are the same.

By default when I try to do it from the administrator I get an error saying that the passwords are the same. Even when I try to add some additional initial in the password does not allow me to save it.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: which django version are you using?

Comment: I´m using Django 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is a one time custom change you want to perform for a specific user, you could most likely do it from the shell, like this:

```
~$ python manage.py shell
>>> user = User.objects.get(...) # get your user
>>> user.set_password("<password>") # will work when password == username
>>> user.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first two entries from AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS in the settings file.

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Comment: great...Then algo it is possible from the admin and not only with the shell.

Answer (score 0):

By default username field in Django must be unique, so you cannot create 2 users with the same username but you can have the same password for any number of users.

Username field is defined in User model